# Google service account gives UNAUTHENTICATED error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

My code runs smoothly on the local server.
On GCP server where python server is started as a linux systemd service,
after few hours of restart it gives me

```
Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
```

Im using gspread to access google spreadsheets.

> Scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"

Comment: Provide your relevant code.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. we need to see what you are doing in order to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in gspread can be fixed using

> client.login()

[Issue on Github](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/618)